# "Priming" or "Training" a compression algorithm to be used for compression/decompression?

Tags: compression

I'm trying to work out if there is a compression algorithm that can be trained beforehand, where you can use the trained data to compress and decompress data.

I don't know exactly how compression algorithms work, but I have an inkling that this is possible.

For example, if I compress these lines independently, it wouldn't compress very well.

```
banana: 1, tree: 2, frog: 3
banana: 7, tree: 9, elephant: 10
```

If I train the compression algorithm with 100's of sample lines beforehand, it would compress very well because it already has a way of mapping "banana" into a code/lookup value.

Pseudocode to help explain my question:

```
# Compressing side

rip = Rip()
trained = rip.train(data)  # once off
send_trained_data_to_clients(trained)

compressed = rip.compress(data)

# And on the other end

rip = Rip()
rip.load_train_data(train)
data = rip.decompress(compressed)
```

Is there a common (i.e. has libraries for popular languages) compression algorithm that let's me do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing, in the parlance of most compression algorithms, would be a preset *dictionary* for the compressor.

I can't speak for all compression libraries, but zlib definitely supports this -- in the exact way you're imagining -- via the `deflateSetDictionary()` and `inflateSetDictionary()` functions. See the [zlib manual](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html) for details.

Comment: Wow, I'm seeing around 2x-5x more compression with a dictionary. That is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

It exists and it is called Lempel-Ziv coding, you can read more here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78

Its one of several 'Dictionary' type lossless compression methods.

LZ is what your Zip archiver basically does.